# Xorg causing unusual High Amount of CPU and Hard Drive use

Tags: xorg, htop

After reboot from update noticed high use of Hard Drive and CPU.
ran HTOP and getting this at top of queue:

/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswtch

Tried X :1 -configure

didn't work. cant figure it?